# Nonlinear Propagation of Discontinuities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

I understand that ahead of the discontinuity (wave front) the initial condition ($u_o(x) \equiv u(x,0)$) is smooth. However the green box goes on to state that $u(x,t)$ is smooth ahead of the wave front.  It is unclear to me whether this has been assumed or it follows from the initial condition. I thought that given a smooth initial condition, we are not guaranteed to have smooth solutions for all time?

Also if $u$ is continuous at the wave front initially is it guaranteed to be continuous on the wave front for all time?